# Delete Extra Space from Values In List

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of numbers in Python all with a extra space in the front.  How do I remove the extra space (so that only the numbers are left)?  A short example is below (note the extra space):

```
List = [' 5432', ' 23421', ' 43242', .......]
```

Comment: you should probably strip before you add if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) here, as the white-space is only at the front:

```
List = [s.lstrip() for s in List]
# ['5432', '23421', '43242', ...]
```

---

Or in this case, seeing as you know how many spaces there are you can just do:

```
List = [s[1:] for s in List]
```

Comment: Nice catch. This is probably better in his situation

Comment: @TimCastelijns It'll be faster, I think.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I went with this one since it was only leading spaces.  Both options worked very well--thank you both for the help!!

Answer (score 6):

For your case, with a list, you can use [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

```
l = [x.strip() for x in List]
```

This will strip both trailing and leading spaces. If you only need to remove leading spaces, go with Alex' solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
map(str.strip, List)
```

or

```
map(lambda l: l.strip(), List)
```